# Library built but not part of rootfs

Tags: yocto

I have built images using yocto(core-image-minimal). I need "libtinfo" library to run my application, but it is not part of rootfs.

I could see the library was built and available under "cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi" folder, but it is not available in rootfs. I have added using IMAGE_INSTALL_append.

My doubt here is, if the library is not required for rootfs(core-image-minimal) then it should not built.

Why the yocto built that library? similar behavior was observed with libudev library also.

Answer (score 3):

Before answering your question, if you have an application which depends on "libtinfo" and your application is also build using yocto (say sample_app.bb), then you should use

```
DEPENDS += "libtinfo"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libtinfo"
```

This will instruct yocto to include the library in rootfs as your application needs it for runtime.

> My doubt here is, if the library is not required for
>   rootfs(core-image-minimal) then it should not built.

Assume you have source for a package which produces binary and also library i.e for example source for `kmod` produces `libkmod` and also `modprobe, insmod, rmmod`. In such cases recipes are written in such a way to produce two different package (based on configuration you can see *.rpm or *.ipk) files i.e `kmod_*.ipk/rpm` and `libkmod2_*.ipk/rpm`.

Based on your real requirement of application you can either use `kmod` or `libkmod` in `RDEPENDS`.

In your case, `libtinfo` is build inside `ncurses` package which may not be required in rootfs by any package.

> Why the yocto built that library? similar behavior was observed with
>   libudev library also.

By default the recipe for the source component `ncurses` or `systemd` includes the configuration (`do_configure`) for `libtinfo` and `libudev` respectively. But it is not included in rootfs, as none of the software needs it during runtime.

You can always check the dependency graph using

```
bitbake -g <recipe name>
```

as mentioned [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#generating-dependency-graphs).

Comment: This solved my problem. I had written a .so agent for NET-SNMP snmpd. Missing RDEPENDS_${PN} was causing the snmpd not being installed to the rootfs, even as my .so agent was. It works now, thanks to you.